# Cannot store data in koa.js app using koa-session

Tags: node.js, koa

I'm using [koa-session](https://github.com/koajs/session) in my koa-app to store some data. So here is my code:

```
/*some code*/
app.use(session(app));
/*some code*/
router.get('/test', async (ctx) => {
    const {session} = ctx;

    console.log(session['test']) // always undefined

    session['test'] = 'test'
});
```

I'm expect to get `undefined` on the first request and `'test'` on the other requests, but I'm always getting undefined. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
ctx.session.test = "testsessiondata"
```